# DataInputStream no lee fichero completo

Tags: java

Con este código añado usuarios nuevos a un fichero binario, lista todos los existentes y permite buscar a uno en concreto y mostrar todos los datos asociados a él:

```
case 1: System.out.println("Introduce nombre: ");
        nombre=teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Introduce apellido: ");
        apellido=teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Introduce año de nacimiento: ");
        nacido=teclado.nextInt();
        dos.writeUTF(nombre);
        dos.writeUTF(apellido);
        dos.writeInt(nacido);
        break;
case 2: try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("file.bin");
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(fis);
            while (dis.available()>0) {
                   System.out.println(dis.readUTF()+" "+dis.readUTF()+" nació en "+dis.readInt());
            }
            fis.close();
       }
       catch (EOFException e) {System.out.println("Fin del fichero.");}
       break;
case 3: System.out.println("Introduce el nombre a buscar: ");
        String buscar=teclado.next();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("file.bin");
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(fis);
            while (dis.available()>0) {
                   if (buscar.compareTo(dis.readUTF())==0) {
                           System.out.println("Los datos completos del usuario son: "+dis.readUTF()+" "+dis.readUTF()+" que nació el "+dis.readInt());
                           break;
                   }
            }
            fis.close();
        }
        catch (EOFException e) {System.out.println("No se encontró el usuario.");}
        break;
```

Añadir user y listar todos funcionan ok, sin embargo no así lo de buscar.
Porqué en el caso 2 el bucle lee el fichero completo sin problemas y en el tercero solo lee 1 ó 2 datos y ya sale lo de "no se encontró usuario"?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en el `case 3` estas leyendo el nombre dentro del `if` y luego para mostrar los datos del usuario lo vuelves a leer, esto ocasiona una excepción ya que usas el método `dis.readInt()` en un orden incorrecto.

```
if (buscar.compareTo(dis.readUTF())==0) {
    System.out.println("Los datos completos del usuario son: "+dis.readUTF()+" "+dis.readUTF()+" que nació el "+dis.readInt());
     break;
}
```

Para solucionarlo basta con:

```
while (dis.available() > 0) {
    String nombre = dis.readUTF();
    if (buscar.compareTo(nombre)==0) {
        System.out.println("Los datos completos del usuario son: " + nombre + " " + dis.readUTF() + " que nació el " + dis.readInt());
        break;
    }
    else{
        dis.readUTF();
        dis.readInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cierto el error inferior al leer de nuevo otro UTF, mil gracias! Por otro lado, la opción de buscar seguirá dando error, ya que con ese método y dado que el fichero contiene realmente UTF1+UTF1+INT1+UTF2+UTF2 etcétera, en el tercer dato del primer usuario ya devolverá excepción, puesto que en el bucle intentará leer un int con la instrucción UTF.

Comment: Tienes razón, solo probé con un registro guardado, acorde a cómo estás guardando y leyendo los datos puedes agregar un else donde leas el apellido y el int en caso de que no sea el registro, ya actualice la respuesta